# BMW Steering Wobble & Brakes Warped

Tags: brakes, bmw, death-wobble

Hi all I'm having a few problems with my BMW E92 320d Coupe (2008) 103,000 miles on the clock. It is such that I've got a wobble through the steering wheel that I cant get to the bottom of.

Its been going on for some time now and I've been puzzled as to what it could be, so I recently took it to BMW to get it looked at, I'm adamant that its not the wheel balance, ans I get a "push" / wobble in the wheel at any speed and it persists under braking. BMW have reluctantly inspected the car and I've had the front left wheel bearing replaced, 4 wheel alignment, 4 new tyres and wheel balance. The issue is persisting. They've said that the suspension isn't bent and all the joints & bushings look good.

I decided to check myself and so jacked the car up at the weekend and took a look. My front right disk appears to be warped by a few mm in one spot and is getting slightly stuck when I rotate it.

I fitted new disks and pads about 10,000 miles ago, and fitted them myself, I cleaned up the caliper front faces and anywhere that made contact as per the BMW guide I followed and re-assembled. I've had no screeching in the brakes, and she stops on a dime. The brakes are under 12 month parts warranty, so I've gone back to the store to get them exchanged but they've told me that disks just dont warp unless there is an underlying issue, though I dont know what? As BMW say my suspension is fine.

Does anyone have some advice? I've spent quite a bit getting this sorted and its turning into a sink for cash.

Thanks!

Comment: Joey, I skimmed the part where you'd replaced the tires, apologies. Hope to read what you find the fix is! Best-

Answer (score 1):

If the wobble is there all the time you've likely got a faulty/failing tyre or a bent wheel rim, its still possible to balance the wheel if this is the case but counteracting the imbalance with wheel weights won't correct the likes of a poorly manufactured tyre or bent rim and thus you would still feel it through the steering, or through the body of the car if it were a rear wheel issue. So I would check properly for those things.

Comment: thanks for the info, I replaced the disks this weekend just gone and I've still got a wobble through the wheel, but the judder under braking has gone away. I'm going to take it to get the wheels re-balanced but I likely believe that a bushing on the lower control arm might have gone, as browsing around online say that can be the likely cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ram a curb? This suggests a bent belt in tire. Try rotating your tires before spending any more money. If getting it off the front wheels fixes the problem, you still want to replace that tire.